# JavaFX Snake Thread.Sleep() does not load FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, thread-sleep

Edit: Answer found! Although CAG did set me on the right track, so I will reward him for it. The correct answer is provided by me though.

I'm making a game of Snake in JavaFX using a Canvas.

I have the game running in a while loop:

1. Print the visual representation of the grid by setting the
   background colors of the correct VBox cells.
2. Wait for input (Thread.sleep(1000).
3. Generate the next visuals.

The problem is, if I use Thread.sleep(), my canvas does not load at all. Behind the scenes, however, the game is still running until I hit a wall and die.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Is thread.sleep() suspending the ability to load and display the JavaFX nodes at all?

```
    Thread gameThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {
            super.start();
            printGridToGUI();
            while (KEEP_PLAYING) {
                generateNextGrid();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SnakeGUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    printGridToGUI();
                });
            }
            /*Stop continuing to play. You either won or lost.*/
            if (WON_GAME) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You lose.");
            }
        }
    };
    gameThread.start();
```

where printGrid() is:

```
/**
 * Prints the grid, with chars in place of on and off areas.
 */
public void printGridToGUI() {
    resetCanvas();
    for (Coordinate c : coordinates) {
        drawCell(c.row, c.col, true);
    }
    drawCell(food.row, food.col, true);
}
```

and resetCanvas is:

```
/**
 * Clears the boolean array, setting all values to false. A quick way to
 * wipe the grid.
 */
public final void resetCanvas() {
    /*Lay out the grid on the canvas.*/
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
            drawCell(row, col, false);
        }
    }
}
```

and drawCell is:

```
/**
 * Draws a cell on the canvas at the specified row and col. The row, col
 * coordinates are translated into x,y coordinates for the graphics context.
 *
 * @param row The row of the cell to paint.
 * @param col The col of the cell to paint.     
 * @param cellON The state of the cell, if it is on or off.
 */
private void drawCell(int row, int col, boolean cellON) {
    /*Translate the row, col value into an x-y cartesian coordinate.*/
    int xCoord = 0 + col * CELL_SIZE;
    int yCoord = 0 + row * CELL_SIZE;
    /*Draw on the canvas.*/
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    gc.fillRect(xCoord, yCoord, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
    if (!cellON) {
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        int BORDER = 1;
        gc.fillRect(xCoord + BORDER, yCoord + BORDER, CELL_SIZE - BORDER, CELL_SIZE - BORDER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using `Thread.sleep()` ? Can you post some code to support your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are invoking `Thread.sleep()` on the FX Application Thread. That thread is responsible for keeping your UI responsive, so causing it to sleep will freeze your UI while leaving your game mechanics in a responsive state (assuming those are executed off of the FX Application Thread).

The solution is to perform your game loop in a new Thread, like so:

```
Thread gameLoop = new Thread(() ->
{
     while (KEEP_PLAYING)
     {
         printGrid(); //<- I assume this prints the state of the grid to the console, and so is safe to execute off of the FX Application Thread
         try
         {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
         catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
         Platform.runLater(() ->
         {
             generateNextGrid(); //<- execute this on the FX Application Thread as it modifies your UI
         });
     }
     if (WON_GAME)
     {
         ...
     }
     else
     {
         ...
     }
});
gameLoop.start();
```

This should prevent any freezing, so long as you are not executing any long-running tasks or invoking sleep on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Actually, clearGrid() and printGrid() modify the JavaFX UI. generateNextGrid() modifies the internal game's boolean[][]. Should I try using a Thread or a Runnable around the code that uses Thread.sleep in the internal game logic? Also, what is the platform.runLater for?

Comment: The runLater method will send the Runnable to be executed on the FX application thread, which you need to do when calling any methods that modify your UI when working in a different thread. So simply switch generateNextGrid() and printGrid() in my answer above.

Comment: I'm still ending up with nothing in the beginning while the code runs in the background. It tells me that sleep is being called properly, but no FXML elements are being seen. Code updated btw.

Comment: You are running your timer thread by sleeping the FX application thread. Your timer thread should not be submitted via runLater(). Your UI updating methods need to be submitted via that method.

Comment: Updated the code. I also switched to using a Canvas.

Comment: And you are still getting the same problem? Are you seeing any updates at all?

Comment: Nothing shows on the canvas. Yet my mouse has a spinning wait cursor. And Sleep is still being called properly. If I lose the game on purpose by just sitting there and letting the invisible snake run into an invisible wall, then the canvas will show.

Comment: Are you handling input correctly? Enough to be able to control the snake, if you could see it? I honestly don't see an immediate reason why your code isn't working.

Comment: It seems that while the game thread is running (with the loop, sleep, and print methods), I can't even enter anything with my mouse or keyboard. Would it be better if I just upload the entire code somewhere? It's not very complex at all. Yet I still don't know why it isn't working. T_T

Comment: Yes. Upload it somewhere. Perhaps the way you are acquiring input is blocking UI updates.

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I'm just about out of luck. :(

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I had to use JavaFX's concurrent package and utilize Task instead of simply Thread.

```
    Task<Boolean> gameTask = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            while (KEEP_PLAYING) {
                generateNextGrid();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(GAME_SPEED_DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SnakeGUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Platform.runLater(() -> printGridToGUI());
            }
            /*Stop continuing to play. You either won or lost.*/
            if (WON_GAME) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You lose.");
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Thread gameThread = new Thread(gameTask);
    gameThread.start();
```

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, if you refactored your logic present in your game loop thread's overidden `start()` method into a new instance of `Runnable` and pass that to the thread, would it offer similar improvements? Also, your `Task` of of type `Boolean` while the overriden `call()` method returns `Object`.